# How to move a sprite without using actions?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am a new user of cocos. I want to move my `ccSprite` from one point to another which can be achieved using `ccMoveto`, but can we achieve it using a schedule method as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For using with the Schedule Method you can use the following code

```
[self schedule:@selector(moveAction1:)]; // This code goes wherever you need to start scheduling

-(void) moveAction1 : (ccTime) dt
{
    [spriteName setPosition:ccp(xPosition,yPosition)];
    xPosition += 0.1f;
    yPosition += 0.1f
    if(xPosition == 320)
        [self unschedule:@selector(moveAction1:)];
}
```

The Above Code would work for you.

**I Would highly recommend to use the ccMoveTo instead of this code.**

Comment: Why do you recommend using ccMoveTo instead?

Comment: As the execution of the ccMoveTo would be faster and also decreases the line of code also. Thats the reason I recommend the ccMoveTo.